# Signal 11 (Segmentation fault) on MPI_Test

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I am receiving segmentation fault on MPI_Test in the following code. The code involves a sender process and a receiver process. The sender process uses non-blocking send to send an integer value to the receiver process 1000000 times. This is just a test code. I am receiving a segmentation fault on MPI_Test in the sender process and am not able to figure out the reason why.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    int rank,nodes;
    int i,j;
    MPI_Status stat;
    int size,wait;
    int msgs = atoi(argv[1]);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nodes);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Request req[msgs][nodes-1],req1;
    if(rank==0){
        size=2;
        for(i=0;i<msgs;i++){
            for(j=1;j<nodes;j++){
                MPI_Isend(&size,1,MPI_INT,
                            j,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&(req[i][j-1]));             
            }
        }
        wait = 1;
        i=0,j=0;
        while(wait){
            printf("at i=%d j=%d\n",i,j);
            MPI_Test(&req[i][j], &wait, &stat);
            wait = 1-wait;
            if(!wait){
                j++;
                if(j==nodes-1){
                    j=0;
                    i++;
                    wait=1;
                }
                else{
                    wait=1;
                }
                if(i==msgs){
                    wait=0;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Finished\n");
    }
    else{
        for(i=0;i<msgs;i++){
            MPI_Irecv (&size,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req1);
            wait = 1;
            while(wait){
                MPI_Test(&req1, &wait, &stat);
                wait = 1-wait;
            }
            if(size!=2){
                printf("Received size=%d rank=%d\n",size,rank);
            }
            size=0;
        }
        printf("Finished rank=%d\n",rank);
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The output of the above program is:-

```
Finished
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
```

after which it gives the segmentation fault

```
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 4576 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

Comment: It's a classical buffer overflow problem. The argument of `sizeof` in all the `malloc()` calls is wrong. It should be `MPI_Status`, not `MPI_Test`.

Comment: @HristoIliev I have edited my code. That was an error but the segmentation fault still persists.

Comment: Your code is technically wrong. You are posting `msgs * (nodes - 1)` non-blocking sends but you only store and wait on the request for the last one. This is not how non-blocking operations should be used. You have to store every single request returned by a non-blocking operation and either wait on it, test it until it completes, or free it with `MPI_Request_free()`. The last one is generally discouraged as you must ensure that all pending operations are complete before calling `MPI_Finalize()`.

Comment: @HristoIliev I have incorporated the changes as advised by you but I am still getting a segmentation fault. Segmentation fault occurs in file openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_vader.so in function vader_prepare_src().

Comment: It could be that you are starting too many non-blocking operations before waiting for their completion. As each outstanding request takes certain resources in the library, there is a practical limit.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks. That was the error. I was issuing too many non-blocking sends.

Comment: I'm having the same problem when calculations are simple and fast. Is there any way to keep track of the number of unprocessed sends, and to know the "practical limit" within the mpi library? Since this is a question, I'll also ask it as a question.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau if you have a question, please ask a new question.